# How to install Apache Tomcat in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, tomcat

I need to practice writing some Java applications.

Can any one help me install Tomcat and tell me how to start and stop the server.

Comment: And What about tomcat8 installing at ubuntu? Is this version of tomcat is available on Ubuntu software Center? Does this code works? sudo apt-get install tomcat8

Answer (score 3):

Look at [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/tomcat.html), the answer is essentially:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

If you want a per-user instance installation (easier for development when starting-and-stopping are desirable) you can install the `tomcat7-user` package and use the utilities it provides (eg `tomcat7-instance-create`). This is all stuff covered by the documentation.

Note: `tomcat6` and `tomcat6-user` packages are also available. `tomcat5` is no longer packaged or recommended.

Comment: @happybuddha I've updated it.