# how can java and apache tomcat 7 install in the ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: 12.04

I new in the ubuntu and i install java in this using oracle VM virtual box. I download jdk after what doing for java install and than after install apache tomcat 7. please help me both software install in ubuntu. Thanks .

Comment: Did you see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk and http://askubuntu.com/questions/338795/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-version-5-and-above-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1- Install Sun JRE 7**

Download the sun jre 7 tar file

Extract the tar file:

```
tar -xvzf jre-7u4-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Move extracted folder to this location:

```
sudo mv jre1.7.0_04 /usr/lib/jvm/
```

Install new java source in system:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_04/bin/java 1
```

Choose default java:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

java version test:

```
java -version
```

Verify the symlinks all point to the new java location:

```
ls -la /etc/alternatives/java*
```

**2- Install Sun JDK 7**

Download the sun jdk 7 tar file

Extract the tar file:

tar -xvzf jdk-7u4-linux-x64.tar.gz

Move extracted folder to this location:

```
sudo mv jdk1.7.0_04 /usr/lib/jvm/
```

Install new java source in system:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/javac 

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/javaws 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/jar 1
```

Choose default java:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

java version test:

```
java -version
```

Verify the symlinks all point to the new java location:

```
ls -la /etc/alternatives/java*
```

**3- Install Tomcat**

to install tomcat easily

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

**4- Autostart Tomcat when booting**

Create the init script in /etc/init.d/tomcat7

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

start() {
 sh /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
}

stop() {
 sh /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/shutdown.sh
}

case $1 in
  start|stop) $1;;
  restart) stop; start;;
  *) echo "Run as $0 <start|stop|restart>"; exit 1;;
esac
```

**Change its permissions and add the correct symlinks automatically:**

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tomcat7
update-rc.d tomcat7 defaults
```

And from now on it will be automatically started and shut down upon entering the appropriate runlevels.

Comment: i using oracle virtualbox terminal for ubuntu than how jre7 download and extract in this.